# Nested dict and pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a *C++* extension bundled with *Python* by using *pybind11*. The extension returns a nested *Python* dict object:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

py::dict cpp_ext(void)  {
    // Variables
    py::dict res;

    // Result
    res["circle"]["x0"] = 0;
    res["circle"]["y0"] = 0;
    res["circle"]["r"] = 1;
    return res;
};
```

It compiles, but gives me the error:

```
KeyError: ('circle',)
```

How should I construct a nested *py::dict* object ?

Comment: What about using `py::dict circle; py::dict res; circle['x0'] = 0; ...; res['circle'] = circle;`?

Comment: Works, @a_guest! Write it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate `dict` for the nested instance and then assign it to the outer one:

```
py::dict cpp_ext(void)  {
    // Variables
    py::dict res;
    py::dict circle;

    // Result
    circle["x0"] = 0;
    circle["y0"] = 0;
    circle["r"] = 1;
    res["circle"] = circle;
    return res;
};
```